# Finding Location of nearby devices in google map using same android app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-location

Am developing an android app like Easy taxi, Uber, lyft. Now I just want to display an icon of users using the app within a specific distance. I have developed a basic app to see my location and I want now to see the location of other devices according to some unique key like their UDIDs.

Can anyone help me to build this logic which will be very much helpful as am not able to proceed further. Since am new to android please let me know the comments for the same

Comment: This is entirely too broad. Please narrow down your concerns to something that can be answered in a couple of paragraphs.

Comment: Have a look at BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) for Android. This seems to be an appt solution for the problem. Documentation would help you to code the basing working model. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: Are you going to use the internet to connect the devices, bluetooth? Will the devices be communicating directly to each other or you waill be using a server? - Please give more details.

Comment: @Ndupza I want to connect them via server and even using internet is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your going to be using a server, you can have all the devices send there current location to the server. Since you say you will have users, I'm assuming your users will have a friend list of people they want to see and be seen by.

So what you can do is to have every user a person is subscribed to send there coordinates periodically. Once person A has the coordinates of person B, Use Android's Proximity Alert to determine wheater person B is close by (Within a certain range of Person A's device)

Then you can perform what ever action you want from there. Here is a tutorial for proximity alert [Android Proximity Alert](http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.com/2012/10/proximity-alerts.html)